# Copy backup file from primary server to secondary server

Tags: sql, backup, jobs, unc

I have a primary SQL Server where backup job is running every night and backup gets stored in local drive.I want to copy that backup and store that in my fail-over SQL Server.

Options I tried:

I created a backup job to save that backup to my fail-over server drive, but I get an error "access is denied for the \xxx.xx.xxx\D$\backup path"

Is there a script to copy the backup and save it in another server drive?

[Please see the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wffgI.png)

I have seen some post relating to this topic, but there is no accepted answer.

Comment: A [scheduled task](https://msdn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/library/windows/desktop/aa446802(v=vs.85).aspx) that runs with sufficient privileges could accomplish this.

Comment: I am working on a script to copy the backup to the secondary server.